# need spacing like the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

need spacing like the screen

```html
   
<section id="team">
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-push-6 ">
 <div class = "col-md-6  ">
 
        <h1 class="cover-heading">About The Movie</h1>

        <p class="">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and
        beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own
        fullscreen background color and photo to make it your own.</p>
    

 
<div class = "col-md-6   ">
director by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Rob W.king</p>

    </div>   
  
  <div class = "col-md-6  ">
casting by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Deb Green</p>
    </div>
   
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
writing  by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Dave Schultz</p>

    </div> 
 
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
costume design by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">colleen Bryant</p>
    </div>
   
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
Director photography  by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Peter la rocque, <span>francis laliberte</span></p>

    </div> 
 
   <div class = "col-md-6  ">
Produced by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">darren benning,<span> jesse bryant,</span> <span>kelly rae buchan</span></p>
    </div>

   </div>
   
</div>
</div>
 </div>
  </section>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: This is completely unclear. Is it an accidental post?

Answer (score 0):

Use `center` tag.

```html
<center>
   
<section id="team">
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-push-6 ">
 <div class = "col-md-6  ">
 
        <h1 class="cover-heading">About The Movie</h1>

        <p class="">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and
        beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own
        fullscreen background color and photo to make it your own.</p>
    

 
<div class = "col-md-6   ">
director by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Rob W.king</p>

    </div>   
  
  <div class = "col-md-6  ">
casting by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Deb Green</p>
    </div>
   
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
writing  by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Dave Schultz</p>

    </div> 
 
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
costume design by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">colleen Bryant</p>
    </div>
   
   <div class = "col-md-6   ">
Director photography  by 
<p style="font-weight: 600;">Peter la rocque, <span>francis laliberte</span></p>

    </div> 
 
   <div class = "col-md-6  ">
Produced by
<p style="font-weight: 600;">darren benning,<span> jesse bryant,</span> <span>kelly rae buchan</span></p>
    </div>

   </div>
   
</div>
</div>
 </div>
  </section>
 
 
 </center>
```